# Conditionally change values of inner dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have dicts in dict and need to change where the value of inner dicts is None to 'None' so it could show in csv file, not to be a blank cell. 
Example:

```
{Object1 : {cellload : 1, cellthr : None, cellcap : 40}
Object2 : {cellload : None, cellthr : 2, cellcap : 40}
...
ObjectN : {cellload : None, cellthr : 5, cellcap : 50}}
```

So, I don't need None or NaN values, that can't be recognized in csv file, I need 'None' as a string.

I've tried this:

```
def replace(main_dif):
    for k, v in main_dif.items():
        for ki, ve in v.items():
            if ve is None:
                ve = "None"
            elif type(ve) == type(main_dif):
                replace(ve)
replace(main_dif)
```

And this:

```
outer = {}
for k, v in main_dif.items():
    inner = {}
    for ki, ve in v.items():
        if ve is None:
            ve == 'None'
        else:
            ve = ve
        inner.update({ki:ve})
    outer.update({k:inner})
```

And None is there just like always, like I did nothing.

Comment: Are you using the standard libs csv module to create the csv? Also, do you want to take care to not alter the original objects?

Comment: No, I don't care. 
Actually, I use xlsx for excel file. Do you have any advice, maybe it's easier than iterating through dicts?

Answer (score 1):

One option is just to brute-force through all the values of all the objects and replace the Nones.

```
for obj in objects:
    for k,v in obj.items():
        if v is None:
            obj[k] = 'None'
```

EDIT It's best to use the python csv module where possible.

In this case we can make a custom DictWriter to handle the None situations for us (it might need tweaking depending on the data).

```
import csv

class NoneSafeWriter(csv.DictWriter):

    def _extract_val(self, rowdict, key):
        v = rowdict.get(key)
        return 'None' if v == None else v

    def _dict_to_list(self, rowdict):
        return [self._extract_val(rowdict, key) for key in self.fieldnames]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['cellload', 'cellthr', 'cellcap']
    writer = NoneSafeWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(objects.values())
```

Comment: I would exploit the fact that  str(None) == 'None'. Just personal preference against this kind of string literal

Comment: I have tried this, but I need to update empty dicts with that new values. That's where i got confused @AidanKane

Comment: I probably wouldn't. You might accidentally end up converting bytes into a string like "b'thing'" if you use `str()` willy-nilly.

Comment: @jovicbg so you have some objects that are totally empty dicts? Do they all have a consistent structure?

Comment: No, no. 
When I tried to write a code I've first create empty dict so I could update it later with new values (after code which is similar to the code you wrote here). Anyway, I don't know how to keep that values

Comment: New update code sample takes a huge amount of time to processing, but I hope it will work.